# installation error: 'Unable to locate package g++-4.8'

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++, sudo

I am trying to install gcc and g++ version 4.8 to run a specific software in Ubuntu 22.04.1

when I perform

```
sudo apt-get install g++-4.8
```

it says

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package g++-4.8
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'g++-4.8'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'g++-4.8'
```

and When I perform

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.8-hppa64' for regex 'gcc-4.8'
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gstreamer1.0-vaapi i965-va-driver intel-media-va-driver libaacs0 libaom3 libass9 libavcodec58 libavformat58 libavutil56 libbdplus0 libbluray2
  libbs2b0 libchromaprint1 libcodec2-1.0 libdav1d5 libflashrom1 libflite1 libftdi1-2 libgme0 libgsm1 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libigdgmm12 liblilv-0-0 libmfx1 libmysofa1
  libnorm1 libopenmpt0 libpgm-5.3-0 libpostproc55 librabbitmq4 librubberband2 libserd-0-0 libshine3 libsnappy1v5 libsord-0-0 libsratom-0-0 libsrt1.4-gnutls libssh-gcrypt-4
  libswresample3 libswscale5 libudfread0 libva-drm2 libva-wayland2 libva-x11-2 libva2 libvdpau1 libvidstab1.1 libx265-199 libxvidcore4 libzimg2 libzmq5 libzvbi-common libzvbi0
  mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers pocketsphinx-en-us va-driver-all vdpau-driver-all
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

What could be done?

Comment: Just `sudo apt install g++`. gcc-4.8 is missing in Ubuntu 22.

Comment: But will it install version 4.8?

Comment: GCC 4.8 is an older version of the GNU Compiler Collection and it is no longer supported by Ubuntu 22.

Comment: So there is no way to install gcc 4.8 in Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: You could possibly recompile gcc-4.8. However the compiler depends on a suite of utilities (binutils) that ultimately depend on the glibc installed. It is all tied up and for that reason it might take you a long time to compile it - if you are ever able to do so.

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly recompile gcc 4.8.5 with the following script. However there is a lot that can go wrong depending on the machine that you are compiling it since the compiler itself depends on a large set of utilities - called the toolchain and they are tightly coupled with the machine's own system libraries, in particular the C standard library.

```bash
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib libstdc++6:i386
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.8.5/gcc-4.8.5.tar.bz2 --no-check-certificate
tar xf gcc-4.8.5.tar.bz2
cd gcc-4.8.5
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd ..
sed -i -e 's/__attribute__/\/\/__attribute__/g' gcc-4.8.5/gcc/cp/cfns.h
sed -i 's/struct ucontext/ucontext_t/g' gcc-4.8.5/libgcc/config/i386/linux-unwind.h
mkdir xgcc-4.8.5
pushd xgcc-4.8.5
$PWD/../gcc-4.8.5/configure --enable-languages=c,c++ --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --enable-plugin --program-suffix=-4.8.5
make MAKEINFO="makeinfo --force" -j
sudo make install -j
```